# Extracting the svn log graphically in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am doing a code review with SVN, now there is a branch where developers have committed the code, I can go to the unix box and type `svn log`.

Can I extract the log graphically in Eclipse?  I have installed the svn plugin in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, the `Team / Show History` item in the context menu for a file / folder / project shows the revision history and the items that were changed in a graphical way.